# Getting value from unbound input razor MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Please forgive me as I am just learning MVC3.

I have 2 db tables one for competitions and one for answers. For each competition there will be 3 answers associated with it.

My Create view is strongly typed to my competition model. What I want to do is add 3 unbound input boxes to that view and retrieve the results in the controller

My controller looks like this

```
Function Create(competition As Competition) As ActionResult
  If ModelState.IsValid Then
    db.Competitions.AddObject(competition)
    db.SaveChanges()
    Return RedirectToAction("Index")
  End If
  ViewBag.ClientID = New SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "ClientName", competition.ClientID)
  Return View(competition)
End Function
```

What i would like to do is something like this

```
Function Create(competition As Competition) As ActionResult
  If ModelState.IsValid Then
    'DIM ANSWERA AS STRING = INPUTA
    'DIM ANSWERB AS STRING = INPUTB
    'DIM ANSWERC AS STRING = INPUTC

    db.Competitions.AddObject(competition)
    db.SaveChanges()
    'SAVE ANSWERS TO ANSWER TABLE

    Return RedirectToAction("Index")
  End If
  ViewBag.ClientID = New SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "ClientName", competition.ClientID)
  Return View(competition)
End Function
```

Sorry if I have not formatted the question properly. Hopefully you get the gist of what I am trying to do

thanks

I got the above working by now I want to be able to edit competition details in a view

```
   Function Edit(id As Integer) As ViewResult
        Dim competition As Competition = db.Competitions.Single(Function(c) c.CompetitionID = id)



       ViewBag.ClientID = New SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "ClientName", competition.ClientID)
        Return View(competition)
    End Function
```

So I scaffold the view which returns my competition details but how do I add 3 input boxes to display the 3 answers associated with that competition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request("NAME")` will look for NAME as the name of a form element, cookie, querystring parameter or server variables.

```
Dim answerA as String = Request("answerA")
Dim answerB as String = Request("answerB")
Dim answerC as String = Request("answerC")
```

To be safe you should probably specifically target the form element called "answerA" using:

```
Dim answerA as String = Request.Form("answerA")
```

but either of the two examples above will work.

Comment: Thanks Brad for reformatting my post. Thanks Matt and bhamlin for the answers both worked

Answer (score 0):

MVC will do the binding for you if the controller parameter name matches the input name. So if your html looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="answerA" />
<input type="text" name="answerB" />
<input type="text" name="answerC" />
```

then your controller can simply be

```
Function Create(competition As Competition, answerA As string, answerB As string, answerC As string) As ActionResult
```

Alternatively you could use an array named `answers` and declare your input fields with names like `answers[0]`, `answers[1]`, etc...